# is AllowOverride working on all subfolders?

Tags: apache-http-server

is AllowOverride working on all subfolders ?

For example, if I specify

```
<Directory />
AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

Is it working on my entire filesystem or only the main folder ?

Comment: Maybe more appropriate for serverfault.com?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It applies to the entire tree under your document root unless some sub-tree also has a `<Directory>` tag set for it. For example, if you had:

```
/
    /foo
    /bar
```

And you said:

```
<Directory />
  AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /foo>
  AllowOverride Indexes
</Directory>
```

Then `/foo` would allow a .htaccess to set directory indexing, but `/bar` would not.